# Handing Remote-User variable with Shibboleth Service Provider

Tags: perl, cgi, shibboleth

Perl CGI web application is my Shibboleth Service Provider.
The cgi protected by Shibb is causing the redirect to Shibboleth IDP.
Authentication successful at the IDP and redirect back to the protected CGI page.
I can see Shibboleth Session variables, but i don't see 'REMOTE_USER' variable set.
Shibboleth2.xml has 'REMOTE-USER="eppn transient-id targeted-id".
What am i doing wrong?? What do i need to do in the attribute configuration files to set the REMOTE_USER(REMOTE-USER) ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have settings in your attribute-map.xml that will create one of eppn, transient-id, targeted-id? I added persistent-id to the aliases as follows:

```
<!-- more OLAT support -->
<Attribute name="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.10" 
       id="Shib-eduPersonTargetedID"
       aliases="Shib-SwissEP-UniqueID persistent-id"> 
  <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="NameIDAttributeDecoder" 
        formatter="$Name!!$NameQualifier!!$SPNameQualifier"/>
</Attribute>
```

and promptly, that value showed up in REMOTE_USER as well.